# why does the app break when i add items to the SQLite DataBase

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am creating a todo task application and i use SQLite database and when i add a new item to the db the app always break i don't know what is this kind of error.
The task class:

```
public class Task {
    String name;
    String discrb;
    int day , month , year ,donecheck ,periocheck;
    public Task()
    {
        donecheck =0;   
    }
}
```

The SQLite code:

```
public class TodoDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todolistdb";
    private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "tasks";
    private static final String KEY_NAME="Task_Name";
    private static final String KEY_DESC ="Description";
    private static final String KEY_DAY="Day";
    private static final String KEY_MON="Month";
    private static final String KEY_YEAR="Year";
    private static final String KEY_DONE="Done";
    private static final String KEY_PRI="Priority";

    public TodoDb(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String create_table= "Create Table" + TABLE_TASKS + " (" + KEY_NAME +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY ," +
        KEY_DESC +" TEXT , " +KEY_DAY +" INTEGER , "+KEY_MON +" INTEGER , "+KEY_YEAR +" INTEGER , "+
        KEY_DONE +" INTEGER , "+KEY_PRI +" INTEGER "+ " ) ";
        db.execSQL(create_table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS);
        onCreate(db); 
    }

    // The add task function
    public void addTask(Task task)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, task.name);
        values.put(KEY_DESC, task.discrb);
        values.put(KEY_DAY, task.day);
        values.put(KEY_MON, task.month);
        values.put(KEY_YEAR, task.year);
        values.put(KEY_DONE, task.donecheck);
        values.put(KEY_PRI, task.periocheck);
        db.insert(TABLE_TASKS,null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

so what is the error in the code

Comment: Post the logcat/stacktrace with your question.

Comment: You missed a space here :

    `String create_table= "Create Table" + TABLE_TASKS`

Add one after `Table`.(i.e :`"Create Table " + TABLE_TASKS)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print this

```
String create_table= "Create Table" + TABLE_TASKS + " (" + KEY_NAME +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY ," +
        KEY_DESC +" TEXT , " +KEY_DAY +" INTEGER , "+KEY_MON +" INTEGER , "+KEY_YEAR +" INTEGER , "+
        KEY_DONE +" INTEGER , "+KEY_PRI +" INTEGER "+ " ) ";
```

There is no space after `Table` so the create table syntax is wrong,give a space like this

```
String create_table= "Create Table " + TABLE_TASKS + " (" + KEY_NAME +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY ," +
            KEY_DESC +" TEXT , " +KEY_DAY +" INTEGER , "+KEY_MON +" INTEGER , "+KEY_YEAR +" INTEGER , "+
            KEY_DONE +" INTEGER , "+KEY_PRI +" INTEGER "+ " ) ";
```